Trying to automate iOS using Appium but not able to scroll and getting the below error
Below is the code that we are using for iOS automation. In this FindElement function, we are using a while loop which will execute for 10 times and try to make the captured element in bounds(in the view) we will do this until the element haven’t is not in bounds or we are out of ScrollMaxRepeats.
What I’m trying to capture and scroll?
I’m capturing the elements of Spotify and Chrome which need scrolling
When I searched for the error( Unhandled endpoint …/wda/scroll on iOS #19816) I found this bug Unhandled endpoint .../wda/scroll on iOS · Issue #19816 · appium/appium · GitHub and according to this when I even downgraded my appium to 6.0.0, I’m still not able to scroll down
My Configuration:
Appium: v2.5.1
uiautomator2@3.0.1
xcuitest@6.2.0 (also checked while downgrading to 6.0.0)
iOS Phone: 17.5.1
protected override IWebElement FindElement(AppiumMobileDriver driver)
{
    var strategyPartList = strategy.StrategyParts.ToList();

    //TODO: Remove the application node.
    if (strategyPartList[0].Value == "XCUIElementTypeApplication")
    {
        strategyPartList.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    var iterationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(options.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds / 10);
    IWebElement element = null;

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(options.Timeout))
    {
        var token = cts.Token;
        var selector = CreateStrategiesBasedSelector(strategyPartList);
        var bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), driver.GetScreenSize());
        var repeatsCount = 0;

        while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false && IsNotPresentedInBounds(element, bounds))
        {
            driver.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = iterationTimeout;
            element = Try(() => FindElement(driver.Driver, selector), driver.Log.Error);

            if (IsNotPresentedInBounds(element, bounds) && options.ScrollDirection != NoScrolling)
            {
                driver.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ManualScrollImplicitWait);

                while (IsNotPresentedInBounds(element, bounds)
                    && token.IsCancellationRequested == false && repeatsCount < options.ScrollMaxRepeats)
                {
                    Try(() => ScrollTo(driver.Driver, options.ScrollDirection.ToLower()), driver.Log.Error);
                    element = Try(() => FindElement(driver.Driver, selector), driver.Log.Error);
                    repeatsCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (IsNotPresentedInBounds(element, bounds))
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return element;
}

private bool IsNotPresentedInBounds(IWebElement element, Rectangle bounds)
{
    return element is null || (element.Displayed || bounds.Contains(element.Location)) == false;
}

private void ScrollTo(IOSDriver driver, string direction)
{
    var scrollObject = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    scrollObject.Add(“direction”, direction);
    driver.ExecuteScript(“mobile: scroll”, scrollObject);
}

protected IWebElement Try(Func @do, Action logError)
{
    try
    {
        return @do();
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logError(ex);
    }
    return null;
}

